# python: how to convert a query string to json string?

Tags: python, json

I want to convert such query string:

```
a=1&b=2
```

to json string

```
{"a":1, "b":2}
```

Any existing solution?

Comment: try http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonurl/1.0.0

Comment: hope this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295236/get-json-object-by-calling-a-url-with-parameters

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Python 3+

```
import json
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

json.dumps(parse_qs("a=1&b=2"))
```

Python 2:

```
import json
from urlparse import parse_qs

json.dumps(parse_qs("a=1&b=2"))
```

In both cases the result is

```
'{"a": ["1"], "b": ["2"]}'
```

This is actually better than your `{"a":1, "b":2}`, because URL query strings can legally contain the same key multiple times, i.e. multiple values per key.

Comment: In other words convert the qs to a dict and then convert that dict to json

Comment: For Python 3 users: `urlparse` is now called `urllib.parse`

Comment: Could be imported as `from urllib import parse as urlparse` without changing the rest of the code.

Comment: If you need to parse as single values then  `parse_qsl` can be used - 
`dict(urlparse.parse_qsl('a=1&b=2'))`

yields 

`'{"a": ["1"], "b": ["2"]}'`

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> strs="a=1&b=2"

>>> {x.split('=')[0]:int(x.split('=')[1]) for x in strs.split("&")}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: @BinChen there's no syntax error. which python version are you using?

Comment: This syntax is available in Python 2.7+ and 3+.
Use `d = dict((key, value) for (key, value) in iterable)` in 2.6 and earlier

Answer (score 6):

#### Python 3.x

```py
from json import dumps
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

dumps(parse_qs("a=1&b=2"))
```

yelds

```py
{"b": ["2"], "a": ["1"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict((itm.split('=')[0],itm.split('=')[1]) for itm in qstring.split('&'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 & 3:

```py
import json

def parse_querystring(query_string):
    variables = dict()

    for item in query_string.split('&'):
        key, value = item.split('=')

        # if value is an int, parse it
        if value.isdigit():
            value = int(value)

        variables[key] = value

    return variables


query_string = 'user=john&uid=10&mail=john@doe.com'
qs = parse_querystring(query_string)

print(repr(qs))
print(json.dumps(qs))
```

The result is

```
{'user': 'john', 'uid': 10, 'mail': 'john@doe.com'}
{"user": "john", "uid": 10, "mail": "john@doe.com"
```