# Convert response.request.body to dict

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests, response, html-tbody

Using the python `requests` library I can issue a `POST`:

```
response = requests.post("https://httpbin.org", data = {"x": 100, "y": 200})
<Response [405]>
```

The returned `requests.Response` object still holds a reference to the original request.

```
response.request
<PreparedRequest [POST]>
```

This enables me to access the parameters of the request later on, e.g.:

```
response.request.body
'x=100&y=200'
```

However, the `data` which was originally passed as a `dict` has already been processed into a string which the server understands.
My goal is to back-convert the body into the original `dict` form.
Is it possible to do that without parsing the string explicitely, e.g. some library function?

I see that this thread [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python) answers a considerable part of this question, but there is a small difference.
In the cited question the urllib is used to split the url into a path and a query string and convert the result in a dict.
However, this question is about parsing a body of a POST request.
So the split does not apply here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python)

Comment: It did actually not answer my question, but it helped me a lot to answer the question myself. The difference is that the cited thread is about url query params but here we have to deal with a body, instead. The urlsplit part of the cited question does not apply here. Instead it is possible to pass the body, directly. But I agree, the cited question is indeed very similar in nature.

Answer (score 2):

The cited thread [URL query parameters to dict python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584545/url-query-parameters-to-dict-python) (
Martijn Pieters's answer) indeed shows how-to convert the query string to a dict. However, one needs to pass the `body` instead of the splitted query, then it works:

```
dict(urllib.parse.parse_qsl(response.request.body))
```

So, now I can answer the question myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to Convert Query string to dict

```
string_query = 'x=100&y=200'
dict_query  = {item.split('=')[0]:int(item.split('=')[1]) for item in string_query.split("&")}


print(dict_query)
```

You can use this Simple Function:

```
def query_to_dict (query : str) -> dict:

    return {item.split('=')[0]:int(item.split('=')[1]) for item in query.split("&")}


body_response = 'x=100&y=200'

dict_query = query_to_dict(body_response)

print(dict_query)
```

find more information on :
[python: how to convert a query string to json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912843/python-how-to-convert-a-query-string-to-json-string)